# Concise way to null check a deeply nested object?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript for browser

I need to test that one deeply embedded property is not `null` and if this condition is `true`, then to change its property. But any its parent can be `null` also. Therefore I am to check each item in the chain... Therefore I write such ugly code:

```
if(window[rootNamespace].vm.tech && 
    window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType &&
    window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType.currentVariant &&
    window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType.currentVariant.currentVersion &&
    window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType.currentVariant.currentVersion.currentWorkSection &&
    window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType.currentVariant.currentVersion.currentWorkSection.currentStageSet){

  window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType.currentVariant.currentVersion
    .currentWorkSection.currentStageSet.selectedEntity = item;
}
```

Is there a shorter method of checking?

Comment: Anyway your going to change this IMO is just going to be less readable. I'd leave it as it is. Your underlying issue is the object structure. The real solution to making this code more readable is to fix the underlying object

Comment: If it's your own object, you should reduce the number of nested objects. Otherwise, I agree with Liam.

Comment: No, I need exactly such tree.

Comment: C# solves it using Null-conditional Operators, but nothing natively in javascript.

Comment: @Agalo, I know it.

Comment: There's a [stage 1 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) for optional chaining similar to C#'s null-conditional operators (`?.`), but it's probably a long way from being standardized, if it will ever be. However, if you're willing to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and non-standard features, [there's a Babel plugin for this proposal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining).

Comment: @Liam, your comment is off-topic.

Comment: @AndreyBushman, after your comment re: the try-catch method and performance, I added an approach below using prototype methods that's cleaner and better on performance. See what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I was the original poster proposing the try-catch method, but based on the discussion on that post you were worried about performance. Here's an alternate approach.)

You can use prototype methods to implement a safe method of accessing subproperties. Here is a method which can safely test for the existence of a nested property:

```
// Indicates whether an object has the indicated nested subproperty, which may be specified with chained dot notation 
// or as separate string arguments.
Object.prototype.hasSubproperty = function() {
    if (arguments.length == 0 || typeof(arguments[0]) != 'string') return false;  
  var properties = arguments[0].indexOf('.') > -1 ? arguments[0].split('.') : arguments;    
  var current = this;
  for(var x = 0; x < properties.length; x++) {
    current = current[properties[x]];
    if ((typeof current) == 'undefined') return false;
  }  
  return true;
};
```

[**A full set of methods can be found here, with sample code.**](https://jsfiddle.net/ewr8mmuq/)

[**Timings**](https://jsfiddle.net/b3j35d0r/) can be run here, and indicate that using **the try-catch method may run a couple of orders of magnitude slower than your original approach when errors are thrown, but is otherwise quite fast**. The prototype methods are more generic and can lead to a more declarative style, while offering much better performance than try-catch misses, but obviously not quite as good as hand-crafting if statements each time and/or try-catch without a miss.

I've also [blogged about this approach](https://digitalrumpus.wordpress.com/2017/08/10/safely-navigating-object-hierarchies-in-javascript-using-prototype-methods/).

Comment: @AndreyBushman This is now the most concise way to access subproperties, without exception handling, as requested... it's a single-line call per access.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax wise I don't think so, but I recommend refactoring at least.

```
var getCurrentStageSet = function(window){
   return window[rootNamespace].vm.tech && 
    window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType &&
    window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType.currentVariant &&
    window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType.currentVariant.currentVersion &&
    window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType.currentVariant.currentVersion.currentWorkSection &&
    window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType.currentVariant.currentVersion.currentWorkSection.currentStageSet
}

var setSelectedEntity = function(currentStageSet, item){
    currentStageSet.selectedEntity = item;
}
```

By abstracting this logic your actual set of the property will be more readable, and reusable:

```
var currentStageSet = getCurrentStageSet(window);
if (currentStageSet){
   setSelectedEntity(currentStageSet, item);
}
```

Comment: I understand your advice, you are right of course. I hoped that exists more compact syntax which I don't know.

Comment: That's more than a bit bloaty.

Comment: I completely understand & agree with the suggestion but I'm not really sure how it answers the question - you still effectively need to write the same code :/

Comment: @James I see your point, however I stated that it cannot be simplified, which is answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

For such a trivial, self-contained piece of code, it's probably not unreasonable to just catch and ignore the error (possibly log) e.g.

```
try {
  if (window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType.currentVariant.currentVersion.currentWorkSection.currentStageSet) {
      window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType.currentVariant.currentVersion.currentWorkSection.currentStageSet = item;
  }
} catch (e) {
   // log the error but continue
}
```

Not sure what else could really go wrong in this type of check, alternatively you could catch a `TypeError` specifically but not sure it would really matter all that much.

I generally wouldn't recommend catch all's but in this case it seems self contained enough to not be a *huge* risk.

Anything beyond that requires effort e.g. building an object decorator or a fluent interface type solution, seems overkill to me though.

Answer (score -1):

You can create some variables to get code more readable

```
  var tech = window[rootNamespace].vm.tech;

  var workType, curVariant, curVer, curWorkSection;

  if(tech){
      workType = tech.currentWorkType
  }

  if(workType){
      curVariant = workType.currentVariant;
  }
  if(curVariant){
      curVer =curVariant.currentVersion;
  }
  if(curVer){
      curWorkSection = curVer.currentWorkSection;
  }
  if(curWorkSection && curWorkSection.currentStageSet){
      curWorkSection.currentStageSet.selectedEntity = item;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the most compact syntax possible in basic JavaScript. It avoids all the null-checking by using error-trapping instead. None of the other answers are as compact because the language is simply missing the feature you're after from C#.

Apparently, I'm being down-voted by the authors of the other, much less compact answers, but this is nevertheless the only single-line answer. Note that other approaches listed here have you creating multiple functions, even. :| If you want compact, this is it.

```
try { window[rootNamespace].vm.tech.currentWorkType.currentVariant.currentVersion
    .currentWorkSection.currentStageSet.selectedEntity = item; } catch (err) {}
```

Comment: I mean you could at least add a brief explanation, also please [format your code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: I try to avoid the loss of productivity, which is inevitable in case of exceptions.

Comment: @AndreyBushman Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you lost productivity typing all that text above in your original post, instead of using error-trapping. A try-catch should have negligible performance impact.

Comment: @AndreyBushman could you elaborate on what you mean by "loss of productivity", and why you think that's "inevitable" with regards to exceptions, I'm intrigued.

Comment: It is true for C# and C++, therefore I think that it is true for other languages too. For example [here](https://sites.google.com/site/bushmansnetlaboratory/sendbox/stati/database/compare) for C# I compared the speed for big data handling with try/catch (when exceptions happen) and without it (when the exceptions don't happen). You can see, that if exceptions often occur it takes 5 min 36 sec, but without it: 0.287 sec.

Comment: @AndreyBushman , the try-catch method is actually quite fast if no exception is thrown. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/b3j35d0r

Comment: I know, but the second option should not be excluded too.